# Is FileStream the safest way to copy a file vs. File.Copy?

Tags: .net, filestream

I would like to copy the file from source to destination directory.  I heard that it is best to do this with a FileStream in case it gets modified later / accessed later.

I am using C# 2.0 and .NET 2.x.

I don't need to determine if the file is open or not or read/write or not. I just need to copy it as is, I have already determined that the file has stopped growing (check every 4 seconds) so that is 'good enough' in my situation.

So should I use MemoryStream or FileStream or File.Copy(..)  and How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use: [`File.Copy(..)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bc33648k.aspx)

How: See the documentation. Also, I recommend checking out the [`Path`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.aspx) class.